# IBM Worklight 6.0 - How to change server host

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I want to change the host value with my IP address when i connect to wifi, but when I build the app it is still localhost.

How to change server host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the host address of your Worklight Development Server:

1. Open the Servers view in Eclipse (if you don't see if, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and search for "servers")
2. Double-click on "Worklight Development Server"
3. Change the `Host name` value from "localhost" to the IP address

Comment: Did you search for the text "servers"? You need to type this text(!). This is an Eclipse feature, it can't not be there. It's there in any Eclipse. Look better.

Comment: @IdanAdar: I can not find Worklight development server in the result list. is there any other way to achieve this or where else can i see "worklight developer server"

Comment: Make sure you are using Worklight 6.0 and Eclipse Java EE 4.2.2; it's there.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse click on menu "Window->Show View->Servers" to display the worklight development server. If "Show View" does not display "Servers" view then click on "Other" option and search for "server" keyword.